# SAP Fiori Elements List Report: Remove the standard "Search" field?

Tags: search, element

With [Fiori Elements](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/smart-templates/),
on the [SAP Fiori List Report](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/list-report-floorplan-sap-fiori-element/),
how do I remove the standard "Search" field?

[image: Fiori Elements List Report search field]

What I'm looking for is a parameter provided by the framework, not a [CSS hack](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/14/fiori-how-to-hide-catalog-button-on-fiori-launchpadhide-what-ever-you-dont-want-to-see/) to hide the element

Comment: Apparently `@Search.searchable` should be the way to go, but adding this annotation to my entity doesn't seem to remove the search field from my generated UI... Credits: https://answers.sap.com/answers/13013763/view.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of architecture are you having in the project, but if you are using SAP CAP in your annotations.cds file you can put the following annotation "Capabilities.SearchRestrictions: {Searchable: false}, ".

This will hide the search filter from your fiori element.

```
annotate CatalogService.<FioriElement> with {
  @UI: {
    headerInfo: {
      typeName: '<EntityType>',
      typeNamePlural: '<EntityTypePlural>',
      description: '<Description>'
    },
    presentationVariant: {
      hideBasicSearch: true
    }
  },
  @Capabilities.SearchRestrictions: {
    Searchable: false
  }
}
```

And it's works :)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpwC3.png)

[How my filter bar looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biqq0.png)

In this documentation you will find the mentioned annotation and different examples for ABAP Annotations, CAP Annotations, XML Annotations:

https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/c0f6592a592e47f9bb6d09900de47412

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using OData V2 or OData V4, but yes you are right having @Search.searchable set to false should do the trick as mentioned here https://help.sap.com/viewer/923180ddb98240829d935862025004d6/Cloud/en-US/4d876cb0230f4cf6b789156ee8b3099b.html

Could you please check your metadata XML and see if `sap:searchable="false"` is set for the entity used on List Report.

Docu - https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3cdebeebb04b4205908140242c9d6817.html

**I see a Note in the docu that this topic is only relevant for OData V2**